# Where is the "Settings" for connecting Office Scripts to VS Code Web?

Tags: visual-studio-code, office-scripts, ms-office-script

Per, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/vscode-for-scripts?source=recommendations#connect-visual-studio-code-to-office-scripts, I should "Under the More options (…) menu, select Editor settings.", but I don't see the ellipse or "Editor Settings" anywhere.

What am I missing?

[image: My Office Script Code Editor]

Comment: You are using ScriptLab. This is different from Office Scripts. Office Scripts are located under the Automate tab.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez - wow.  that is not a very obvious distinction, but I get it now.  for others, this helped explain the differences - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71935936/office-scripts-vs-office-lab#:~:text=Office%20Scripts%20is%20currently%20only,to%20be%20a%20development%20environment.

Please put this as the answer so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ScriptLab. This is different from Office Scripts. Office Scripts are located under the Automate tab on the ribbon. You can see the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71941457/16864869)